# How can OpenStack can auto install the OS into a VM?

Tags: operating-system, openstack

When I watching the [openstack launch a VM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hKcgv441HsQ):

in the `5:12/7:06`, you see there choose a image then launch a VM, it will install the OS.

[image]

I want to know the technologies of the auto deployment of OS.

How can OpenStack can auto install the OS into a VM?

---

**EDIT-01**

I mean how can OpenStack can deploy OS into a VM. 
Such as the Windows can use Windows WDS to deploy the OS, the Linux can use kickstart to deploy the OS. 
how about the OpenStack can deploy both the Windows and Linux?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of images type which you can use with Openstack Platform. Some of them are:
RAW, QCOW2, ISO, VHD, VMDK, DOCKER, PLOOP. 
Out of which QCOW2 format is a live OS image which does not require OS installation, as you can use it directly without any installation. Same is for VHD, VMDK image format.

If you have used ISO as a format this will install an OS first & then you can use it just like normal OS installation. But it takes time to install an OS instead use Qcow2 images for faster deployments.
Upload an image to your Openstack Platform then while launching an instance select that uploaded image in Image section.

Answer (score 0):

This service probably has a folder containing various OS images. These OS images were prepared ahead of time to work with OpenStack's VMM and network. The OS image is supplied to the VM, and when the VM launches, it initializes the OS.